# Url Rewriting with Dynamic URL's in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I've already looked at some URL rewriting questions on stack and gone about implementing the solutions that were posted but I can't get it to work. I am using dynamic URL's for posts. So, each post has an id and the original url looks like: `localhost/post.php?=id`. I currently am trying to get just `localhost/post/id`.

Here is a snippet of the .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^/post/([0-9]+)/?$ /post.php?=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . routing.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)?$ post.php?id=$1
```

You must write your link: `<a href="post/<?=$id;?>"><?=$title;?></a>`

And file post.php

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/post/([0-9]+)/?$ /post.php?=$1
                                         ^ perhaps a key for this value?
```

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to work. In my code the link to the post is 
<a href="post.php?id=$id">$title</a>. Would that affect the way the url is rewritten?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```